# Iterate through array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, iterator

I am trying to iterate through the array of objects but somehow not getting it right. Can somone please let me know where i am going wrong.

Here is the data

```
const response = {
    "pass": 1,
    "fail": 2,
    "projects_all": [
        {
            "projects": [
                {
                    "name": "Project1",
                    "current": null,
                    "previous": {
                        "environment": "qa4nc",
                        "status": "UNKNOWN",
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "projects": [
                {
                    "name": "Project2",
                    "current": null,
                    "previous": {
                        "environment": "qa4nc",
                        "status": "FAIL",
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Project3",
                    "status": "LIVE",
                    "current": null,
                    "previous": {
                        "environment": "qa4nc",
                        "status": "UNKNOWN",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And here is the code i tried

```
if(response) {
  response?.projects_all?.forEach((projects) => {
     projects.forEach(project) => {
       if(project.previous !== null) {
         //do something here
       }
    });
 });
}
```

I am trying to iterate through this array of objects but it says projects not iterable. Any help is appreciated to make me understand where i am going wrong.

Comment: Can you share the error trace?

Comment: `projects_all` is an array of objects with a `projects` key mapped to yet another array. You're naming each object in `projects_all` the `projects` variable, but you're not accessing the `projects` key inside of those variables that holds the array you're after. Change it to `projects.projects.forEach(...)`.

Comment: In your code, you need to call `projects.projects.forEach` - since each `projects` is an object with the key `projects` in it. I'd rename the outer one to `project` singular to disambiguate, as in `response?.projects_all?.forEach((project) => { project.projects.forEach`

Comment: Hi @Perry- It just says projects.forEach is not a function and highlights to this line of code -> projects.forEach(project) => {

Comment: jinx! 10 more to go...

Comment: Aagh.. got it. thanks for the help Andy n Zulfe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing iterating over an array properly. A good idea is to format the JSON object that you plan to iterate over. So that you can see what are the arrays and objects, and at what hierarchy.

```
if (response) {
  response?.projects_all?.forEach((project) => {
    project?.projects?.forEach((project) => {
      console.log(project?.name);
    });
  }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`response?.projects_all?.forEach((projects) => {`

This is the exact correct way to start the code. The problem that happens next is you apparently misunderstand what `projects` means in the following context

You do `projects.forEach(project)` as if you think `projects` is as array. `projects` is not an array at this point, it is an object that looks like this:

```
        {
            "projects": [
                {
                    "name": "Project1",
                    "current": null,
                    "previous": {
                        "environment": "qa4nc",
                        "status": "UNKNOWN",
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

So I would actually want to do `projects.projects.forEach(project => { ... })`, or you could change the variable name from `projects` so it makes more sense to read.

Answer (score 1):

First, determine what shape your response object currently has.
By using the `?.` operator your essentially muting JS built in error reporting.

From the context, I assume your response actually looks like this:

```js
console.log(response);
{
   data: {
      projects_all: [ ... ]
   }
}
```

Therefore your existing code using `response?.projects_all` doesn't actually hit the `projects_all` property inside your response.

Can you try the following:

```js
response.data.projects_all.forEach((project) => {
   console.info("Project: ", project);
   project.projects.forEach((project) => {
      console.log(project, project?.name);
   });
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't have a `data` key inside your response object, you can omit it in the loop:

```js
response.data.projects_all.forEach((project) => {
   console.info("Project: ", project);
   project.projects.forEach((project) => {
      console.log(project, project?.name);
   });
});
```